# What's the time complexity of character array initialization?

Tags: c, time-complexity

As usually reading through stuff I got this question in mind.
If I have a character array initialization like below , what will be the time complexity for this statement?

```
char array[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
```

Will it actually execute 5 time to assign each variable; as we do in loop. If assumption is true why is it so?

Comment: I'd assume any non-idiotic compiler will do it in `O(n)` with no more than 5 assignments to the 5 different memory locations. (and maybe less if it decides to vectorize)

Comment: If the array is just as in your example, the compiler would just put the array values as a consecutive memory chunk in the applications data segment, and let `array` point to that. No initialization or loop at all.

Comment: @Joachim: not if `array` is on the stack, it needs to be initialized locally then. (But there's nothing in the standard that says how a compiler should do that, so the question isn't really answerable - check the compiler's output. GCC does 5 byte moves here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on where the declaration occurs and the compiler's intelligence, it could be O(1) or O(n). some cases:

1. global declaration, smart compiler would put it in data section, already initialized, thus O(1)
2. local declaration, if proven to be read only by a smart compiler, it could be like above, plus a reference assignment to the array, still O(1) however
3. local declaration, read write, could be storage allocation + 5 assignment (clearly O(n) OR storage allocation + array data copy (like 2, but the data gets copied instead of only the reference). the latter could be O(1) with vectorized code (well... more or less because it depends on quite a lot of things)

Comment: For 2., I think there must be more than that. It would also be necessary that the compiler is able to prove that there is never a comparison of the base address of the array. Two instances of the "same" array, e.g from different recursive calls must always prove to be different. The only case I know of where such folding is allowed are `const` qualified compound literals.

Comment: @JensGustedt without `const`, it's perhaps necessary. but a real smart compiler could treat it as if it's declared `const`, regardless it's declared so or not.

Comment: Even with `const`, for two objects that are distinct a test with `==` for their addresses must return `false`.  Two instances of the same variable that correspond to two different recursive calls fulfill that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(N).  It might be a fast or efficient O(N).  And if it's a statically allocated array, the initialization will only be done once.

But in any case, it's O(N).

Note that even if it's an array that's placed in the binary image of the program (because the compiler determines that the array is never modified), it's still an O(N) operation to initialize it, even though the initialization might occur before the program event reaches `main()` or is done as part of the program image load.

It's O(N) because whatever does the initialization has to write to each location of the array, so an array that's 100 times as long as another will have on the order of 100 times more operations to perform to complete the initialization.

Comment: I don't get your point. As far as I know the values of such a static initialization are placed in the binary image. Usually that part of the binary is then `mmap`ed (or similar) with "copy on write". The overhead of initialization then only occurs whence a value is written to a specific location. In particular a variable that is never accessed doesn't have any overhead at all. In terms of bigO notation the total cost is `O(M)` where `M` is the number for accesses to individual locations of the array. So in terms of bigO no overhead at all. The constant hidden in the bigO is pagesize, though.

Answer (score 0):

As other said, it can be done in O(n) time.

But it can never be O(1)!!
How can you write in n memory locations(whatever type of memory we have) in less time? 
O(1) means that the operation doesn't depend on the size of the input. I don't want to bring turing machines to the discussion, but somewhere during runtime there will always be a O(n) operation with the above statement.

Comment: No, this analysis is too coarse. You'd have to measure it in `M` the number of times an array element is accessed by the program. See my comment for Micheal Burr's answer.

Comment: @User - You can write multiple characters at once, especially when the string is this short. On my 64-bit machine the compiler moves 8 characters at a time using a single register.

Comment: @BoPersson yes but the number of characters you can move at once is limited.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity will be simply 0. Not O or o (n). 
The place for the array will be set with the start values BEFORE the program runs. Place and values will be prepared on the compiling stage and set on linking stage.

There will be NO commands for realisation of the line mentioned. And NO time spent.